# Is there a way to bypass Directx Effect Files?

Tags: opengl, architecture, directx

I am now trying to abstract my rendering pipeline, and I've been able to abstract OpenGL fairly easily. But now I have ran into a rather ugly problem with Directx.

Most of my knowledge about Dx9, 10, and 11 makes use of effect files. Something that openGL distinctly lacks. I know that this file does not have to be used. However, by the way all of DX's documentation had been written, it seems like it is required and there is no way around it.

Can anyone give me a lead here?

Comment: The Effects system has always been optional, and Effects for Direct3D 11 is essentially deprecated. See [What's the difference between an .fx and .hlsl file anyhow?](https://fx11.codeplex.com/discussions/551307) and [Is Effects 11 deprecated](https://fx11.codeplex.com/discussions/450240)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[FXC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb232919%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`D3DXCompileShader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172731(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`D3DCompile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd607324(v=vs.85).aspx) to compile basic HLSL vertex/pixel/... shaders (single entry point, just like GLSL).

Then create shaders from the generated shader blobs using API functions such as [`CreatePixelShader` (D3D9)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174359%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`CreatePixelShader` (D3D10/11)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476513(v=vs.85).aspx). Then apply these shaders with [`SetPixelShader` (D3D9)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174450(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`PSSetShader` (D3D10,11)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476472(v=vs.85).aspx).

To transfer uniform data to shaders, since you want to deal with both D3D9 and 10/11, I'd suggest getting used to mapping uniform values manually by appending code like `: register(c0)` (D3D9 uniform values) and `: register(b0)` (for D3D10/11 uniform blocks). A [documentation page on shader constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509581%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) could help make sense of this.

[This tutorial](http://directxtutorial.com/Lesson.aspx?lessonid=11-4-5) shows how to compile non-effect shaders from file in D3D11.